# Simple contract does not get deployed on Remix on testnet

Tags: solidity, remix

Basically the title. Contract is very simple, only function is the constructor.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract MyContract{
    uint8[][][] public cube;

    constructor(){
        for(uint8 i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            for(uint8 j = 0; j < 10; j++){
                for(uint8 k = 0; k < 10; k++){ 
                    cube[i][j][k] = i + j + k;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Deploying the contract]

Trying to deploy the contract results in an error "creation of MyContract errored: VM error: revert"

Changing the constructor to "payable" did not change anything.

I am just learning about Solidity so I would appreciate a detailed explanation about what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in me not initializing the sub-arrays inside this multi-dimential array. Solved by either providing size for the arrays (which I did since I knew they needed to be of size 10) `uint8[10][10][10] public cube;` or by initializing the sub-arrays in the loops.